# Editing a table

Tags: tables

I want to edit the table to the left below, into the second screenshot to the right (the three tiny short lines indicate that this line should not be there, the 'Test' below should not be there too).

Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
     \textbf{Test} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\ \hline 
     {\textbf{U}} \\ \hline
     {a} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
     {b} & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
     {c} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
     {d} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
     {\textbf{W}}\\ \hline
     {e} & \textbf{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ \hline
     {f} & 0 & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & 0 \\ \hline
     {g} & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \textbf{1} \\ \hline

 \end{tabular}  

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this? Using `\cline` and some `multicolumn`s.

[image: d4rtyTabular]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
    & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Test}\\\cline{2-6}
    \textbf{Test} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\ \hline 
    \textbf{U}&\multicolumn{5}{c|}{} \\ \hline
    a & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
    b & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
    c & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
    d & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
    \textbf{W}&\multicolumn{5}{c|}{}\\ \hline
    e & \textbf{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ \hline
    f & 0 & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & 0 \\ \hline
    g & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \textbf{1} \\ \hline

\end{tabular}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: @Mico the ones i just deleted? Or do you mean others?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do by using booktabs. This is the easiest way to present the data in tables

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}

    \toprule
    \textbf{Test} & & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\ \midrule
     {\textbf{U}}& & & & & \\ \midrule
    & {a} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \midrule
    & {b} & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \midrule
    & {c} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \midrule
    & {d} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \midrule
    {\textbf{W}}& & & & & \\ \midrule
     &{e} & \textbf{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ \midrule
    & {f} & 0 & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & 0 \\ \midrule
     &{g} & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \textbf{1} \\ \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}  

 \end{document}
```

[image: booktabstbl]

Comment: A couple of comments: (i) I think the word "Test" is supposed to be in the top row, spanning columns 2 thru 6. (ii) Since you're using the superior `booktabs` package, you may also want to show just how much better the table can look if the interior horizontal lines are omitted along with all those vertical lines.